# How to set disabled button property using a function?

Tags: angular, button

I'm trying:

- To have a button disabled by default.
- After 4 seconds, the button will be enabled by **using a function**.

Maximilian instructor used a constructor. But I want to use a function instead, so I wrote below function but it's not working (the button is always enabled).

**servers.component.ts**:

```
export class ServersComponent implements OnInit {

  allowNewServer = false;

  AllowNewServerFunction(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      return this.allowNewServer = true;
    }, 4000);
  }

}
```

**servers.component.html**:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
    [disabled]="AllowNewServerFunction()">Add Server</button>
```

Comment: What do you think `AllowNewServerFunction` method is returning?

Answer (score 3):

Here is stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/disabled-button-duration

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  allowNewServer = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.AllowNewServerFunction();
  }
  AllowNewServerFunction() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.allowNewServer = true;
   
    }, 4000);
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
    [disabled]="allowNewServer">Add Server</button>
```

Comment: You don't need to `return true;` in the `AllowNewServerFunction` method since it's not doing anything :-) I thought about this too but OP says: _"Maximilian instructor used a constructor. But I want to use a function instead"_. So I thought using constructor or life-cycles were out of bounds

Comment: my bad forgot to save changes. Thanks

Comment: Hi sorry for delay, i'll test it soon with my own project & will make sure to reply back.

Answer (score 2):

The method itself must return a Boolean. Right now it's just setting a property which is not used anywhere in html.

Try changing function to return Boolean instead of setting the variable

```
AllowNewServerFunction(
    { 
      setTimeout(()=>{
           return  true;
      },  4000);
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: Hi sorry for delay, i'll test it soon with my own project & will make sure to reply back.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I can think of is to provide an observable with a delay if you really want to return a function type thing:

```js
export class ServersComponent {
  isDisabled = of(true).pipe(delay(4000));
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary"
    [disabled]="isDisabled | async">Add Server</button>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtxe2x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: This is better way can achieve this 

Comment: Hi sorry for delay, i'll test it soon with my own project & will make sure to reply back.